# Listbox is disabled and vertical scrollbar goes way with silverlight

Tags: silverlight, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, listbox, scrollbar

I have this

```
        <ListBox  
                ItemsSource="{Binding Students}" 
                SelectionMode="Extended" 
                Name="listStudents" 
                Height="430" 
                IsEnabled="{Binding CanUpdateNumber}">
         </ListBox>
```

When IsEnabled is true and items in the listbox are more then vertical scrollbar is present.
When IsEnabled is false all the items are disabeld (which is true) and the scrollbar is off so cant see all the items in the listbox.

How do i make scrollbar present when the IsEnabled is false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your ListBox with a ScrollViewer control, like this:

```
 <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="430" Width="110" Padding="0">
    <ListBox 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Students}" 
        SelectionMode="Extended" 
        Name="listStudents" 
        IsEnabled="{Binding CanUpdateNumber}"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
        BorderThickness="0">
    </ListBox>
 </ScrollViewer>
```

Found here:
http://manny-grewal.blogspot.be/2010/09/enable-scroll-in-disabled-listbox-in.html

**Edit:**

I think I spotted the mistake I made in this post. Set the height in the Scrollviewer and remove the height from the ListBox.

Comment: Strange, it works here...Can you specify which result you get? Don't forget to add the `Padding="0"` in the Scrollviewer and the `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"` in the Listbox.

Comment: Edited the post. Can you try again?